# Solution for Dirichlet problem in $\mathbb{R}^N$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

At our course, the instructor discussed the Dirichlet problem
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
-\Delta u(x)=f(x) & x\in\mathbb{R}^N  \\
\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}u(x)=0
\end{array}
\right.,$$
where $f(x)=e^{-|x|^2}$.

He tried to prove that $u=E*f$ (convolution) is the solution to this problem, where $E$ is the fundamental solution corresponding to Laplace operator:
$$E(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln{|x|} & N=2 \\
-\frac{1}{\omega_N|x|^{N-2}} & N\geq3
\end{array}
\right.,$$
where $\omega_N$ is the surface area of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^N$.

The problem arose when he had to prove that $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}u(x)=0$. For $N\geq3$, he obtained $$u(x)=c_N\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|y|^{2-N}e^{-|x-y|^2}dy=c'_N\int_0^\infty r\int_{S^{N-1}}e^{-|x|^2-r^2+2r\,x\cdot\sigma}d\sigma dr.$$

Using the majoration $|x\cdot\sigma|\leq|x|\cdot|\sigma|$, he said that the integral which is obtained (depending on $x$) converges to $0$ as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$. Later, he observed that this is not correct and we wonder how we can prove that
$$\int_0^\infty r\int_{S^{N-1}}e^{-|x|^2-r^2+2r\,x\cdot\sigma}d\sigma dr\xrightarrow{|x|\rightarrow\infty}0.$$

Does anyone know what we should try?

Comment: Isn't the leading term in there $-|x|^2$? He goes much faster than $x$ to $\infty$.

Comment: It's a bit tricky because you have $2rx\cdot \sigma$ and $r\to \infty$ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

$$u(x) = c_N\int_{|y|\leq |x|/2} |y|^{2-N} e^{-|x-y|^2} \, dy + c_N\int_{|y| > |x|/2} |y|^{2-N} e^{-|x-y|^2} \, dy.$$

In the first integral you have $|x-y|\geq |x|/2$ and in the second $|y|^{2-N} \leq C|x|^{2-N}.$ This gives

$$|u(x)| \leq C\left(e^{-|x|^2/4} \int_{|y|\leq |x|/2} |y|^{2-N} \, dy + |x|^{2-N}\right).$$

Then compute $\int_{|y|\leq |x|/2} |y|^{2-N}\, dy= C|x|^2$ to get

$$|u(x)| \leq C( |x|^2e^{-|x|^2/4} + |x|^{2-N}).$$

Now you can send $|x|\to \infty$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. This is very helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!